# Cannot find Twitter element by name using Selenium and Chrome Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to remotely log into twitter and tweet using selenium and Chrome webdriver but I can't seem to get it before I do anything else I want to just test if I can write into the username and password areas but I cant even do that.

Here is my Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://twitter.com")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("session[username_or_email]")
elem.send_keys("test")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

When I try this it opens the command prompt to run chromedriver.exe then it opens the chrome window but then nothing else happens and it gives me this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python27\Project\Auth2.py", line 10, in <module>
    elem.send_keys("test")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line     162, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': typing})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line   228, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 165, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 152, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchWindowException: Message: u'no such window: target window already closed\nfrom     unknown error: web view not found\n  (Session info: chrome=26.0.1410.64)\n  (Driver info:     chromedriver=0.8,platform=Windows NT 5.1 SP3 x86)'
```

Can anyone tell me what's the problem and how to fix it!

Comment: i got it to work i guess i just needed to use `driver.find_element_by_id` instead of `driver.find_element_by_name` and it worked just fine!

Comment: but now im wondering if i can do this with out the window popping up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `find_element_by_id`, `find_element_by_xpath` or `find_element_by_css_selector` should be used in this particular case.

I suspect `elem = driver.find_element_by_name("session[username_or_email]")` won't work because of the square brackets.

For anyone else who needs to handle square brackets using Selenium, using css selector or xpath should be easier as shown in the following example (square brackets are in class names in this example):

```html
<label class="username js-username">
    <span>Username or email</span>
    <input class="session[username_or_email]" type="text" autocomplete="on" />
</label>
```

```python
# I suspect this won't work?
driver.find_element_by_class_name("session[username_or_email]")

# won't work, as the special meaning of square brackets in css selector
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".session[username_or_email]")

# use these
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='session[username_or_email]']")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='session[username_or_email]']") # same as usual
```

Answer (score 2):

this is what worked for me

```
EmailElement = driver.find_element_by_name('session[username_or_email]')

PasswordElement = driver.find_element_by_name('session[password]')

EmailElement.send_keys('email/username_goes_here')

PasswordElement.send_keys('password_goes_here')
```